# angular2: Componentless Routes vs Empty path routes

Tags: angular, angular2-routing

According to angular2 final version, routes can be defined in the following way:

**Componentless Route:** Which will instantiate URLs and do not care about the component

**Empty path routes:** Which will instantiate Components and do not care about the URLs.

Is that right? Can anyone give me a proper example in detail so I can get a better insight?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

A componentless route makes only sense when there are child routes and the configuration of the componentless route (like resolvers or guards) apply to all child routes.
This just saves redundant configuration.

With an empty path route there is to distinguish whether it has `patchMatch:`full`or`prefix`, where`full`matches a route with an empty path and`prefix` matches without consuming a part of the path and the router continues finding other matching routes with the remaining path (which is the same with other routes just that the remainder is the full path).

Comment: Ok (+1). I can't fully understand the `empty path routes`. :( Can you give a working example? Can I combine these two?

Comment: Of course you can combine them. Empty path routes are the same as other routes, just what is consumed from the full path on match is different.  I don't have an example ready but if you build a Plunker and run into troubles I can have a look.